# Python Pandas - select best match from set returned by extractall

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a regular expression to match dates in an irregular data set. Some dates may not have the month or day defined, some have the year specified with 2 digits, some with 4.
I have defined a regex which is doing pretty well, but on many lines, it has more than one match. I would like to define a lambda to select the best match, but I'm not sure how to do so with Python/Pandas.

Here is my regex (I'm defining it piecewise to make it more understandable and re-usable):

```
year = "(?P<year>(?:(?:(?:20)|(?:19)?)\d{2})"
day = "(?P<day>[0123]?\d)"
month = "(?P<month>[01]?\d)"
separator = "[ /-]"

regex = f'(?:{month}{separator})?(?:{day}{separator})?{year})'
```

I'm reading data from a file and creating a dataframe with one column 'original_text':

```
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        doc.append(line)

df = pd.DataFrame(doc, columns=['original_text'])
```

Here I'm looking at a slice of my results that match my regex:

```
print(df['original'].str.extractall(regex)[124:142])
```

> ```
>          month  day  year
>    match
> 67 0         7    6    91
>    1       NaN  NaN    10
> 68 0         1   21    87
> 69 0       NaN  NaN    24
>    1        11    3  1985
> 70 0         7   04    82
>    1       NaN  NaN    90
>    2       NaN  NaN    80
> 71 0         4   13    89
> 72 0       NaN  NaN    25
>    1         7   11    77
>    2       NaN  NaN    50
>    3       NaN  NaN    28
>    4       NaN  NaN    16
>    5       NaN  NaN    83
>    6        12  NaN    36
>    7       NaN  NaN    20
>    8         9   36    30
> ```

In many cases extractall returns multiple matches. For example, on row 67, the text is:

> 7/6/91 SOS-10 Total Score:

This row has two matches. The first one is my preferred match. In other cases, the preferred match is not the first one, for example, row 69:

> 24 yo right handed woman with history of large right frontal mass s/p resection 11/3/1985 who had recent urgent R cranial wound revision and placement of L EVD for declining vision...

and row 72:

> Lithium 0.25 (7/11/77).  LFTS wnl.  Urine tox neg.  Serum tox + fluoxetine 500; otherwise neg.  TSH 3.28.  BUN/Cr: 16/0.83.  Lipids unremarkable.  B12 363, Folate >20.  CBC: 4.9/36/308 Pertinent Medical Review of Systems Constitutional:

I would like to apply a function to the set of matches to select the one most likely to constitute a proper date, and only return that one. The end result would look something like this:

> ```
>    month  day  year
> 67     7    6    91
> 68     1   21    87
> 69    11    3  1985
> 70     7   04    82
> 71     4   13    89
> 72     7   11    77
> ```

Pseudocode here for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
def get_best_match(matches) {
    match = < best match from matches>
    return match
}

dates = df['original'].str.extractall(regex).<lambda that calls get_best_match on each row of this set>
```

Comment: can you just just do `df.dropna()` then select the first row after grouping with the row number

Comment: `df.dropna().reset_index()` Then group with the first column, then filter

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu `df.dropna()` looks like it could be very useful, but I'm looking for a more nuanced approach. The data set I'm working with may produce results with empty values that are still valid, so I wouldn't want to discard everything with an empty value. What I'm trying to do is find a way to apply a lambda to the group of matches in order to select the best match from that group. The best I've come up with so far is using `df.apply()` to apply a lambda to the individual rows.

Comment: I believe maybe the a more suitable regex might be of help. It is really difficult to help since you did not provide an example